# How to display SVGs (clip-path) on IE and Edge with smooth edges

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, microsoft-edge, clip-path

I've got an SVG that contains 3 `<image>` tags and a `<rect>` that all have a clip-path applied to them.  On all browsers except IEs and Edge the clip-path is applied smoothly along the edges, but on IE it appears jagged.

I've tried applying sharp-rendering="crispEdges"/sharp-rendering="geometricPrecision" to the SVG and all nested elements with no luck.

Here's a screenshot on Edge - Windows 10:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhGAL.jpg

The code:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 2300 820" width="100%" height="100%" xml:space="preserve" shape-rendering="sharpEdges">
    <image width="100%" height="100%" clip-path="url(#myClip)" class="banner-fill" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="{{ content.field_banner_image.0 }}" shape-rendering="sharpEdges"></image>
    <image clip-path="url(#myClip)" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="{{ content.field_banner_image.0 }}" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none" shape-rendering="sharpEdges"></image>
    <rect clip-path="url(#myClip)" height="100%" width="100%" x="0" y"0" style="fill:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);" shape-rendering="sharpEdges"></rect>
    <image clip-path="url(#myClip)" class="banner-blob" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/themes/custom/turley/media/images/banners/shape-4.svg" x="-177px" y="-150px" width="1600" height="1600" shape-rendering="sharpEdges"></image>
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="myClip">
            <path class="st0" d="M2300,0H0v695.2c680.4,90.6,1336.6,143.5,1779.3,118.6c204.4-7.5,383-85,520.7-218.1V0z" shape-rendering="sharpEdges"></path>
        </clipPath>
    </defs></svg>
```

Comment: Hi Lewis, first go in IE Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages". save changes. now when you display the f12 tool in IE the console tab will list markup errors, including svg markup errors.

Comment: <aside> the svg source you provided is no good for us to debug. Copy and paste the computed source from the IE dev tool, which will include the resolved paths to the image files. f12>DOM Explorer tab, find>SVG, right click on the selected svg element or its parent div in the DOM Explorer and select copy outer html from the context menu.